# HTML CSS how do I remove the background color of text

Tags: html, css, background

An issue I'm amazed I couldn't solve on my own. I can not seem to remove the standard white background from any text added to my page. I have tried being broad and making the body and p tags transparent as well as being specific with classes. No luck.

[The white text background at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSSsF.jpg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.backgroundImage {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url(desk1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

p {
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.divText {
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.text1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundImage"></div>
<div class="divText">
  <p class="text1">
    many words are written here to take up lots and lots of space. i do this to test the scrolling of my background image thank you very very much
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try putting background-color as than(0,0,0,0.0)

Comment: `<div class="backgroundImage"></div>
<div class="divText">...</div>` are two siblings, so the background of the first one remains in the first one.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to make it so the text is on top of the picture with a transparent background?

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is to put the writing on top of the image, you can try this structure in your HTML, because there is actually no background there, it's just situated below the image. To position the text well over the image, you can try using flex-box.

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;}

.backgroundImage{
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url(desk1.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 100vh;}

body {
background: transparent;
background-color: transparent;
}

.text1{
font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="luxStyle1.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="backgroundImage">
      <p class="text1">
              many words are written here to take up lots and lots of space. i do this to test the scrolling of my background image thank you very very much
      </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Source of this problem comes from the div with backgroundImage class, it is placed before the divText, and there are a few solutions that I can thing of right now:

1. Delete background image and place css code of it to .divText so the divText has that background (this is what my snippet shows, i also deleted extra lines that specify transparency, you don't need to necessarily delete them, I just wanted to get rid of it since there is no use for it anymore)
2. Same as number one but place the .backgroundImage class data to body so the whole page has the same background, No.1 solution affects the background of divText
3. Use position absolute to put .divText to inside of the .backgroundImage

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.backgroundImage {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url(desk1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}

.divText {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url(desk1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.text1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divText">
  <p class="text1">
    many words are written here to take up lots and lots of space. i do this to test the scrolling of my background image thank you very very much
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use @Mr-montasir 's solution, it's much practical I don't know how I didn't think of it :D

Answer (score 0):

The background is transparent already because the body default background color is white, so to fix that just put the text inside the div with the backgound image like this:

```
<div class="backgroundImage">
    <div class="divText">
      <p class="text1">
        many words are written here to take up lots and lots of space. i do this to test the scrolling of my background image thank you very very much
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```